# NodeJS javascript-obfuscator error: "All stringArrayEncoding's elements must be unique"

Tags: javascript, node.js, obfuscation

Using [javascript-obfuscator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/javascript-obfuscator) on a JS file and getting the following errors..

```
ReferenceError: Validation failed. errors:
`stringArrayEncoding` errors:
    - All stringArrayEncoding's elements must be unique
,    - stringArrayEncoding must be an array

    at new o (/path/to/node_modules/javascript-obfuscator/dist/index.js:2:366749)
    at _createInstance (/path/to/node_modules/inversify/lib/resolution/instantiation.js:29:12)
    at Object.resolveInstance (/path/to/node_modules/inversify/lib/resolution/instantiation.js:49:18)
    at /path/to/node_modules/inversify/lib/resolution/resolver.js:73:42
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.resolveInstance (/path/to/node_modules/inversify/lib/resolution/instantiation.js:48:67)
    at /path/to/node_modules/inversify/lib/resolution/resolver.js:73:42
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.resolveInstance (/path/to/node_modules/inversify/lib/resolution/instantiation.js:48:67)
    at /path/to/node_modules/inversify/lib/resolution/resolver.js:73:42
```

Code causing the error:

```
obfuscatorSettings = { //obfuscator options being used
        compact: true,
        controlFlowFlattening: true,
        controlFlowFlatteningThreshold: 0.75,
        deadCodeInjection: true,
        deadCodeInjectionThreshold: 0.4,
        debugProtection: false,
        debugProtectionInterval: false,
        disableConsoleOutput: false,
        identifierNamesGenerator: 'hexadecimal',
        identifiersPrefix: 'UniqueId',
        log: false,
        renameGlobals: false,
        rotateStringArray: true,
        selfDefending: true,
        shuffleStringArray: true,
        splitStrings: true,
        splitStringsChunkLength: 10,
        stringArray: true,
        stringArrayEncoding: 'base64',
        stringArrayThreshold: 0.75,
        transformObjectKeys: true,
        unicodeEscapeSequence: false
    }
obfuscatedCode = require('javascript-obfuscator').obfuscate(JSFileContents, obfuscatorSettings); //Error here
```

A change to the JS File is what resulted in the error.  Trying to figure out which change is the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

The error message also says "*stringArrayEncoding must be an array*".

Try: `stringArrayEncoding: ['base64'],`

[Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/javascript-obfuscator#user-content-stringarrayencoding)

Comment: That did it.  Thank you.